# Stop a program from executing that is running in Linux server side

Tags: linux

I'm running my program in Linux server using:

```
$  nohup <your_script> &
```

It keeps running as I wanted. But I want to stop it. Do anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a programming forum, this question is more appropriate for http://serverfault.com

Comment: This is a pretty basic question - it could go to http://superuser.com, too.

Comment: If your shell has job control (bash has) , you can kill the proces with `kill %1`, assuming `1` is the jobnumber. (which  can be obtained by the `jobs` command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the process ID, then kill the process:

```
ps aux | grep <your_script>
```

The second number is your PID, take that number and pass it to `kill`:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Alternatively, you can also use `killall`:

```
killall <your_script>
```

Comment: Don't kill -9. Start by being modest, with kill -TERM or something like that. (a program cannot set a handler for SIGKILL, so it can not perform any pre-mortem housekeeping, such as closing files nicely, closing connections gracefully, removing shared memory, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Get the pid of the process with *ps*, and then run *kill*:

```
Kill -9 pid
```

Comment: Don't kill -9. Start by being modest, with `kill -TERM` or something like that. (a program cannot set a handler for SIGKILL, so it can not perform any pre-mortem housekeeping, such as removing shared memory etc)